# how to load sql/session content to a div from loaded div

Tags: php, jquery, sql

I have been researching for the last two days, and have found nothing.

structure:

index.php:

```
    <head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="function.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div>
     <div><a href="" class="testcat" id="1">Show</a></div> *-->if I click this link data loads into DIV below by function.js without reloading*
     <div id="producten"></div> *-->testpage.php loads here perfect,
the code of testpage.php makes by while loop other links.
Here I want to click on a link to load next data in div id=information 
without reloading the index.php so the data in the first DIV stay visible 
and I dont know how to do that*
     <div id="information"></div> *-->testpage2.php have to load data from sql in this DIV*
    </div>

    </body>
```

function.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".testcat").click(function() {
        var testid = $(this).attr("id");
        var datastring = 'id='+ testid ;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "testpage.php",
            data: datastring,
            cache: false,
            success: function(res) {
            $('#producten').html("<div class='loading'><img src='IMG/loading.gif' /></div>")
                .hide()
                .fadeIn(2000, function() {
                $('#producten').html(res);
            })
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); 

});
```

testpage.php and testpage2.php are PDO code for sql data.

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand what you want. Could you show the full code of `testpage.php` and `testpage2.php` and specify in which second div you want the information loaded?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are pertaining into a AJAX solution.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to attach your click handlers with `on` so that dynamically added content still has the same ajax handlers available to them:

Add whatever information is needed to differentiate one click from the next, ie

```
<a href='...' data-resultdiv='production'
```

Then, cleaning up your handler a bit: I assume you want the ajax request to go to the href of the link, and that you want to show "loading" *immediately* (instead of waiting for the request to complete).

Finally, to cancel the anchor's default behavior of browsing to the page referenced by the `href`, you can return false;

```
$(document).on("click", "a", function() {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    var successDiv = $(this).data("resultdiv");
    $('#' + successDiv).html("<div class='loading'><img src='IMG/loading.gif' /></div>");
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: href,
       data: datastring,
       cache: false,
       success: function(res) {
           $('#' + successDiv).hide().html(res).fadeIn(2000);
       }       
    }
    return false;
});
```

And of course if you only want this to run for certain anchors, you can put a selector on your call to on

```
$(document).on("click", "a.someClass", function() {
```